# Running a stored procedure in a SqlDataSource on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures, sqldatasource

I am building a C# ASP.NET page where I want to call a stored procedure in a database.

I have setup a `SqlDataSource` which points to the stored procedure. Parameters are obtained from the Web's control directly (TextBox)

I have a button, when the user clicks it it should run the stored procedure, so I was going to add code like this :

```
mySqlDataSource.run()
```

or

```
mySqlDataSource.exec()
```

or

```
mySqlDataSource.storedProcedure()
```

but of course none of these methods exist.

How do I initial the stored procedure? and how do I get the value returned by the stored procedure please?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `mySqlDataSource.Select()`.  [SqlDataSource.Select Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: What `database` product do you have? You should have to use `Provider` API instead of `rough` SqlDataSource control.

Comment: You mean you are not binding it to any databound control like GridView etc?

Comment: @AVD I am connecting to MSSQL DB, I can't seem to find a "Provider" component in Visual Studio tho.

Comment: @AVD but I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: @codingbiz no it is not bound to anything, I need to obtain the user input before running the stored procedure therefore it must be initiated by a button. I am not sure how would binding it to a GridView work with TextBox inputs.

Comment: and what does the PROC do - INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE, or ?

Comment: @codingbiz It verifies the parameters and performs an update on a table

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the method you are looking for is `DataBind`. Call it using `mySqlDataSource.DataBind()`

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
  ID="sds2" 
  runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="..."
  SelectCommand="spTest"      
  SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
  >
  <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" PropertyName="Text"
                              Name="ParamName" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="0" />
  </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" DataSourceID="sds2"></asp:GridView>
```

The stored procedure is executed when you call `DataBind`. The DataBind method is called automatically if the DataSourceID property of the GridView control refers to a valid data source control.

Comment: `spTest` is the name of the stored procedure to execute.

Comment: But what if you want to pass a parameter from code behind to the sqldatasource without re-defining the SQL command, connection, etc in C#? I was hoping for an answer like mySqlDataSource.Select(wsMyParmsHere);

Comment: In the Selecting event for your SQL Datasource, you could have something like `e.Command.Parameters["@LocationID"].Value = localvar;`

Answer (score 2):

To init a SP from sqldatasource is easy:

```
mySqlDataSource.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
mySqlDataSource.UpdateCommand = "sp_name";
mySqlDataSource.Update();
```

To get a return value from your SP, I would suggest to use SqlCommand:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1177022.aspx

make sure you have a parameter created with ParameterDirection set to ReturnValue or Output

Answer (score 1):

```
//HTML:

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:testConnectionString %>" 
        onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" SelectCommand="testProc_sp" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" onclick="Button3_Click" Text="Button" />



//c#:

 protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
    }
```